# How to get rid of the animation during reveal opening

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 4 reveal to reveal an image. The reveal opens with an animation as shown in the examples in the documentation page. I see in the documentation that it is possible to configure reveal using Javascript. There is a parameter named 'animation'.

From the Foundation 3 docs I see that the options available are fadeAndPop, fade and none. How can I configure so as to get rid of the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Reveal docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) configuration options can only be passed at initialization time. [This article](http://zurb.com/article/1180/how-to-use-foundation-4-s-faster-better-a) shows how to do that. So you want:

```
$(document).foundation('reveal', {animation: 'none'})
```